# Can I get notifications on new posts on a tag?

Tags: support, tags, notifications

I would like to subscribe to a feature to receive a notification when a person asks a question under [the Python tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) on Stack Overflow. How can I do it?

Comment: Would RSS work for you?